# Music Player how to make the UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I am surely able to run the music on my **music player**. But how am i really supposed to create a UI? I want a kind of UI for the music player in which there will be a pause, a start, and other basic buttons along with a proceeding bar as the music progresses.

Comment: Android question? Use XML and ImageButtons. Please show your attempts at a layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class.

Then Add `ImageButtons` for the player action (play , pause etc...)

Here is a good place for free icons

https://material.io/icons/

Comment: And then how am i supposed to set up the java for the following. And i also want to make a proceeding bar as the music progresses.

Comment: @Knattic use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html and do a little bit of math using duration of sound